# How do I upgrade npm to support Node.js v14.0.0 on MacOS?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've recently installed newest version of node 14.0.0 on my computer (macOS Catalina). Wanted to start new project with. Initially I wanted to install express with `npm install --save express` and got below warning logs:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v14.0.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN ProjectName@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I am wondering if this is issue on my setup side and I should reinstall node (possibly downgrade?) or something different.

Thank you for you patience and support!

Comment: How was Node installed? I suggest using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for controlling node versions.

Comment: node was install by `brew install node`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm does not support Node.js v10.0.0 but older version installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453520/npm-does-not-support-node-js-v10-0-0-but-older-version-installed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :

```
Mac:
sudo npm uninstall -g npm // uninstalls globally 

Windows:
npm uninstall -g npm // uninstalls globally
```

Then:

Re-install [node](https://nodejs.org/en/)

**NOTE:** Ensure that your `PATH` points to where `node` is installed 
e.g. If node installed at `/usr/local/bin/node`, ensure `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`

Comment: Terminal answer with following message `zsh: command not found: npm`

Comment: Have you checked if your `PATH` points to where `node` is installed?

Comment: I did - `/usr/local/bin` was in `PATH`.

I've installed [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) with file .pkg from website. 

It fixed the issue upon reinit my project.

It looked like brew install did not install npm properly.

Comment: i can't use npm to uninstall npm because "npm does not support Node.js v14.13.0" ...

Comment: i fixed it by manually deleting the npm folders and then reinstalling nodejs

Comment: The OP asked about MacOS, and AFAICT your answer is correct for Mac.  On Windows, you really should uninstall NPM by removing the NodeJS from the "Add or remove programs" Settings window, then using the Node MSI installer to install both Node and NPM at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

For windows. Follow this instructions here https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

- PREREQUISITE: Uninstall existing node & npm
- Install nvm-windows
- Run `nvm install <version>`
- Run `nvm use <version>`

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to dependencies from libraries like Heroku or yarn etc.., . Another hack-of-a-solution if you are stuck on this issue on MAC or any unix based system is:

Step 1: `cd /Users/username/`

Step 2: Do a `ls -ltrh` to list hidden files and locate `.npm/ and .npm-packages/`

Step 3: Sudo `rm -rf .npm/`

Step 4: Sudo `rm -rf .npm-packages/`

Step 5: Run `brew reinstall node`

Step 6: Run `npm install -g npm@7.13.0` or any other version if there is a minor update needed

Step 7: Run `npm install -g @angular/cli` or any other framework to test

Step 8: Check versions `node -v` and `npm --version`

This issue should now be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

on windows:
*Uninstall node.js (Windows Add/Remove programs)
*Manually delete the npm folder from your user profile (%APPDATA%/roaming/npm)
*Install node.js (from Windows 10 LTS download MSI)